# Angular application in IIS vs Node server

Tags: node.js, angular, iis

we have developed a Angular 4 application.

I have windows server 2012 R2 as production box

should i use node server to host the angular application, or IIS can also be used without any issue ?

i do not have any background experience so please suggest

Answer (score 1):

I USUALLY USE IIS without any probs .. Node.js usually for developing purpose (with angular cli and webpack dev server) .. but then in production and in PrePRod (so on my servers) i usuall use IIS...

just `check the webconfig file`...

for example ..
1 -  `set default page as Index.html`

2 - `set rewrite rules for redirect on Index.html ..`

..

and the `be sure to have installed the URL REWRITE MODULE on IIS`

Hope it helps you!